# Capacitance information using fingerprint scanner on android device

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, fingerprint

I've done a great amount of research, searched through API's, and looked through the forums for an answer. Finally decided to join stackoverflow!

THE PROBLEM:

I want to get the capacitance of the finger through a piece of hardware on the phone.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

I've come to the conclusion that, although the phone uses a capacitive touch screen, accessing the capacitance information on the touch screen is not possible (unless somebody knows how to?). I've considered using the fingerprint scanner, being that it is a capacitive sensor (the fingerprint scanner on the S5). Is there any way to access only the capacitance value instead of the image from the fingerprint scanner?

Comment: And your requirement is to use only on device hardware and not external devices connected via Arduino and Android Accessory Development Kit - correct?

Answer (score 0):

Some phones or tablets embed fingerprint sensor and a SDK to obtain template (list of minutiae) or picture. SDK also provide method to enroll and match.

Comment: @Chris G, is it useful ?